# Token authentication with Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

Using ASPNET webapi, it's very easy to setup a 3. party authority for token validation. I've looked around to do the same with Azure Functions but haven't found an answer yet. Is it possible yet and also if it is, can it be done not using Azure AD, but integrate something like Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible yet and also if it is, can it be done not using Azure AD, but integrate something like Firebase Authentication?

Yes, it is possible. Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@alex.wauters/how-to-integrate-a-firebase-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-b5c0f01a0c24).

Firebase is an application platform from Google which offers many useful services to get your mobile or web app project started up quickly. To authenticate your users, the Firebase Auth service offers registration screens and authorization functionalities.

Comment: I already have Firebase Auth running with my mobile app. According to the article I still need Azure AD to integrate with functions and make something for validation. With ASPNET WebAPI it's still seems a lot easier to make the integration with a 3rd party auth provider